# iPhone 4S linked to old Apple Id

Tags: apple-id, iphone, restore

I'm trying to clean my old iPhone for selling it.  iCloud address is a different Apple Id from the one I'm using now. 
I can not see a way to reset the password for the old linked Apple id.

What should I do?

Comment: It's somewhat confusing what you mean by the second and third sentences. Please correct me if I'm wrong: you have an iPhone linked to an old Apple ID that you want to erase, but you've forgotten the password and are unable to recover it (why?).

Comment: I have an old I phone that is a 4s.  I want to send it in so I can get some money but I need to erase all the info on it.  I am not able to do this because to do this I need to enter the old and now invalid apple id which is not my current apple id.  I have tried all of the pass words that I have used to no avail.  I do not see any way to get a new pass word requested for this old apple id.

Comment: [Can you not recover your Apple ID?](https://iforgot.apple.com)

Answer (score 1):

**Remove it from the iCould via Web Browswer**

You'll have to log into icloud.com with the AppleID that the phone is locked to.

Click on `Find iPhone`.  It will bring up a Map and try to locate all of the devices linked to that AppleID.

Click on `All Devices` drop down at the top.

Click on the `iPhone 4s` in question.  It will have the name of the phone (for example - Users iPhone)

Click `Remove from Account`

Next time you reset the device it will no longer be linked to that Apple ID.

**Remove it from iCloud on the Phone**

If you can still get into the phone. Follow these Steps:

- Open the Settings App
- Touch iCloud
- Touch Find My iPhone
- Turn Find My iPhone to Off Position
- Enter the password of the iCloud account
- ***Note - these steps might be slightly different depending on iOS version

Next time you reset the device it will no longer be linked to that AppleID.

Just FYI iCloud account and AppleID are synonymous these days.