# iPhone 4s asking for old Apple ID but nowhere to type code

Tags: ios, apple-id, activation-lock

My phone was disabled so I connected it with iTunes. We unlocked it and now it is requesting the old Apple ID. I don't know the old one but my brother made a password reset, and now it gave us a code but there is nowhere to type it in on the phone. The screen didn't reset for us to type in the code. What do I do? Of iPhone 4s

Comment: Good work finding the new ask. To confirm - is your situation really much different than the linked question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232068/iphone-4s-linked-to-old-apple-id Or just you need an answer too?

Comment: Can you confirm you are stuck at activation lock? That’s easy - you power off the phone and then remove that phone from the old accunt online (your brother can do that once the phone in question is powered off). If it’s not activation lock - if you can describe or get a picture of the lock error that will help us help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No input field for Apple ID Verification Code](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266968/no-input-field-for-apple-id-verification-code)

Answer (score 5):

You can type in that code immediately after your password in the password field.

> **What if I use two-factor authentication on a device running older software?**
>
> If you use two-factor authentication with devices running
>   older OS versions, you might be asked to add your six-digit
>   verification code to the end of your password when signing in. Get
>   your verification code from a trusted device running iOS 9 and later
>   or OS X El Capitan and later, or have it sent to your trusted phone
>   number. Then type your password followed by the six-digit verification
>   code directly into the password field.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

Comment: Aah - so it’s a TFA sort of issue and not activation lock. Well figured out.

Comment: @bmike that is a guess from my part. I'm not really sure that's the real issue.. but that's what I read in the question.